# N-th rooth of the number complexity misunderstanding

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double d;
    int n, i;
    double lower=0, upper=1, middle, product;
    scanf("%lf %d", &d, &n);
    if (d>upper) upper=d;
    while (upper-lower>0.000005)
    {
        middle=(upper+lower)/2;
        product=1;
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            product*=middle;
        if (product>d) upper=middle;
        else lower=middle;
    }
    printf ("%.5f\n",(lower+upper)/2);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this algorithm have O(n*log(d/0.000005)) complexity? The (d/0.000005) part is confusing for me.

Comment: Constants should be factored out, so that: O(n * log(d/some_constant)) == O(n * log(d))

Comment: @danh 0.000005 is not multiplied to n but its inside log. You just can't take any number out you see

Comment: @shashwat: in this case you can, because `log(d/C)` is `log(d) - log(C)` and if `C` is a constant, so is `log(C)`. Then O(n * (log(d) - C')) is `O(n * log(d) - n * C')` which is indeed `O(n * log(d))`. But in general, you do have a point.

Comment: Well put, @rici.  However, the other commenter doesn't make a valid point "in general" either:  In general, we consider only the long term growth of continuous, monotonic functions.  For the sake of complexity, we always factor constants out of logs, polynomials, exponentials etc.

Comment: @danh: using `^` for exponentiation, I'd say that `O(2^n)` is not the same as either `O(3^n)` or `O(2^(2n))`. It is the same as `O(2*(2^n))`. It depends where the constant goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer loop is running a binary search, which divides the search range in half on every iteration. It will continue until the search range has been reduced to `0.000005`. So the question is, "how many times do you need to divide by 2 to reduce the search range from `d` (which is the starting range) to `0.000005`? The answer is `log_2(d/0.000005)`.

The inner loop runs `n` times. So the overall running time is proportional to

```
n * log_2(d/0.000005)
```

But that's not the complexity, because big-O ignores constants. So the base of the `log` is ignored. And the division is ignored because

```
n * log(d/0.000005) = n * (log(d) - log(0.000005))
```

So the complexity of the algorithm is O(n log(d)).